# <AJAX> basic format in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have ajax code as following.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<c:url value="$....json" />',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { userId : userId },
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
        if(data.result == '0') {
            $(opener.document).find('#userId').val(userId);                             
            $(opener.document).find('#entDtm').text(entDtm);
            $('#endWeek').append("<option value=''>CHOOSE</option>");
```

My question is

1) what is the difference between

```
$(opener.document).find('#userId').val(userId);
```

and

```
$(opener.document).find('#entDtm').text(entDtm);
```

where upper one is .val and bottom one is .text

2) Difference between $(opener.document) and $('#id')

3) Difference between.find and .append

Would appreciate your answer

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.val()**: usually sets the "value" attribute on the selected element (e.g. an input text field). The behavior is different in case of select tag.

**.text()**: sets the text as inner text between open and close tag of the element (e.g. a span tag), you have **.html()** also that sets the inner HTML (not in simple text but evaluating HTML tags).

**$(opener.document)**: uses a previously declared variable as selector. The variable must contains a reference to a DOM element.

**$('#id')**: finds a DOM element using the unique ID (`<div id='test'>`).

**.find()**: allows you to find and element inside the DOM tree, the requested argument is a jQuery valid selector (eg. by ID with `#test` or by class with `.class` or with tag and attributes like `input[name="test"])`.

**.append()**: allows you to append desidered content to the end of selected element.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I really wanted to know what .find does also. Could you please explain that? Thanks :)

Comment: find() finds an element that matches the selector you passed to it *inside* the the Jquery DOM object. (in this case, it returns #userId and #entDtm elements inside the document)